# java SWT clicking a button

Tags: java, button, swt

when i create an interface, using SWT, i create a button and then i need when clicking this button new class is called, i tried this:

```
Button btnNewButton_1 = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
btnNewButton_1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

    public void widgetSelected (SelectionEvent e){
        Holder hold = new Holder();
        hold.create_holderTrust();
    }
});
```

but when i click the button the class is not called,
Can anyone please try to hepl me, i need this in my project

Comment: please read  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: thank you, just because i am new, so my way of asking questions need some experiance. I will improve it next time

Answer (score 0):

The click of the button should work, try this:

```
Button btnNewButton_1 = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
btnNewButton_1.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {

    public void widgetSelected (SelectionEvent e){

        System.out.println("TEST");

        Holder hold = new Holder();
        hold.create_holderTrust();
    }
});
```

If `TEST` is printed in the console then something is wrong with your `hold.create_holderTrust()` call. You could also set a breakpoint to figure that out.

Comment: when i try to print "test", it is shown in the console, but the classe does not called, do i have to define this class in plugin.xml file or in other class ??

Comment: i am using this code in a plugin development project, and i want to call another class after clicking on a button, do i have to define this class in other plasse

Comment: So the button works, for testing you could place the class in the same package (directory) as the class which creates the button. Do you get an error message? Are you using Eclipse? Eclipse should show you an error in the code if the class is not visible.
Also maybe add an "print" in the beginning of create_holderTrust().